# ActiveRecord and map in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, dictionary

I make select

```
m_repeats = Event.where(:repeat => 'monthly').where("schedule < ?", date.end_of_month)
```

Then I need change the shedule (it is date field) in each element.

I try to do:

```
m_repeats.map{ |elem| elem.schedule.year = date.today.year, elem.schedule.month = date.today.month }
```

But I get the errors:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'schedule' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE `events`.`repeat` = 'monthly' AND (schedule < '2013-04-30')
```

or
    undefined method `schedule' for #

What is correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the events table has a schedule field in schema.rb? Can you access Event.first.schedule?

Comment: Yes.   create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.date     "shedule"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "repeat"
  end

Also my "Where(...)" selection works fine, and I see the error only when add mapping code

Comment: Yeah, but the `map` is not the reason you're getting a db error, that looks like the second `where`.

Comment: I think Frans is correct -- you're seeing the error at the `map` because ActiveRecord doesn't execute a query until you ask for the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use only one where statement like

```
m_repeats = Event.where('events.repeat = ? AND events.schedule < ?', 'monthly', date.end_of_month)
```

or explicitly name the table of your query on the schedule column like

```
m_repeats = Event.where(:repeat => 'monthly').where("events.schedule < ?", date.end_of_month)
```

I don't think that your map method is causing the problem, because the select of the Events takes place at the call of the map method and there you get a clear problem in your select query.

Comment: First code - Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.schedule' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE (events.repeat = 'monthly' AND events.schedule < '2013-04-30')

Comment: m_repeats = where('repeat = ? AND schedule < ?', 'monthly', date.end_of_month) return Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'monthly' AND schedule < '2013-04-30')' at line 1: SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE (repeat = 'monthly' AND schedule < '2013-04-30')

Comment: Ok, in that case you should check your database again to 1) Are all migrations done 2) Is your schema correct 3) did you reload your console if you are using the console

Comment: Alsi I see at the error page that error cause in view string 
<%= calendar.day(:day_method => :shedule) do |date, events| %>

May be something incorrect with data structure?

Comment: Oh my god, it was really grammar error :) 'schedule' instead of 'shedule' Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

it was really grammar error :) 'schedule' instead of 'shedule'